# Makefile pattern rules on multiple subdirectories

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu-make

So I have a GNU Makefile to compile all .cpp files from my Game directory and its subdirectories into .o files in build/obj folder (no subdirectories in that one). My problem is that only the first file in the list is compiled, I know the problem is that I need a build pattern, but I can't think of a way to implement this in each subdirectory. I've tried several things, looping through all the directories using foreach, removing the filename from the directory and putting a wildcard in place, but all to no avail. Any help?

```
SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build
OBJ_DIR=$(BUILD_DIR)/obj

GAME_DIR=$(SRC_DIR)/Game
GAME_DIRS=$(GAME_DIR)/Classes $(GAME_DIR)/ConVars $(GAME_DIR)/EventListener $(GAME_DIR)/Functions $(GAME_DIR)/Interfaces $(GAME_DIR)/Modules $(GAME_DIR)/NetVars $(GAME_DIR)/Offsets $(GAME_DIR)

SRC_FILES=$(foreach dir,$(GAME_DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
OBJ_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_FILES))))

all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -shared $^ -o $@ -std=c++17 -lgdi32

$(OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_FILES)
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$(OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_FILES)
```

It says, each object file depends on *ALL* the source files.  The `SRC_FILES` variable expands to the same list of files every time, so for every object file the list of prerequisites is the same, so every time you compile it you use `$<` which expands to the first prerequisite, so the same file is compiled over and over.

In a pattern rule the part of the name that matches the pattern must be identical between the target and prerequisite, and the part of the name that doesn't match the pattern must be static.

As a result there is no way to use one single pattern rule to build all your source files like this.  There are a number of options you have:

You can create multiple pattern rules, one for each source directory (it's easier to avoid static pattern rules in this situation):

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.c : Classes/%.cpp
         ...
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.c : ConVars/%.cpp
         ...
```

Or, you can put the object files into a subdirectory of OBJ_DIR, but with the same prefix.  So instead of `Classes/class.cpp` building to `obj/class.o`, it would build to `obj/Classes/class.o`.  For this you'd use:

```
OBJ_FILES=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC_FILES)))

$(OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

(note, it's not really right to use `CC` and `CFLAGS` for building C++ code; those variables are traditionally used to build C code.  `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` are the best variables for building C++ code)

The other option is to use VPATH, like this:

```
 VPATH = $(GAME_DIRS)

 $(OBJ_FILES): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp
          $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```